# Why I can't create a cursor in SQL?

Tags: sql, cursor, datagrip

Searching the entire internet for the corect syntax for creating a cursor in sql. 
Begin with this:

```
DECLARE cursorName CURSOR FOR
SELECT Name
FROM Student;

continue with this: BEGIN
DECLARE cursorNume CURSOR FOR
SELECT Nume
FROM Student;
END;
```

And still error. I am using Datagrip.
Can anyone help me?

Comment: Which DBMS product are you using?

Comment: Up to now, you declared the cursor. Now you have to open and iterate and within that iteration, you can do your operation.
Finally you have to close it

Answer (score 0):

https://www.sqlservertutorial.net/sql-server-stored-procedures/sql-server-cursor/

This link offers the steps to use a cursor in the database explaining all the baby steps involved. Here's how I have followed it:

```
DECLARE
@current_transaction_id bigint;
    
DECLARE 
cursor_for_transactionIds CURSOR FOR SELECT ProfileId FROM EHR.Profiles;
    
OPEN cursor_for_transactionIds; 
FETCH NEXT FROM cursor_for_transactionIds INTO @current_transaction_id;

WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0 
BEGIN 

PRINT @current_transaction_id 
    
FETCH NEXT FROM cursor_for_transactionIds into @current_transaction_id; 
END;

CLOSE cursor_for_transactionIds; 
DEALLOCATE cursor_for_transactionIds;
```

Although it has been quite a long when this question was asked. Sharing the solution to the question for those who'll encounter the same issue in the future. This is why you've landed on this question.